# Not able to query the JSON data converted from CSV

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mern

I'm trying to run below JSON data which is basically from CSV file. I am able to get output only in
`db.learning.find({})`

while when I try to access specific document then it dont give any output.

**JSON** data is here below

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("624edebb78036379835d29a7"),
    "pmid" : 32339032,
    "ti" : "SAFETY AND EFFICACY OF DDP4-INHIBITORS FOR MANAGEMENT OF HOSPITALIZED GENERAL MEDICINE AND SURGERY PATIENTS WITH TYPE 2 DIABETES.",
    "year" : "2020",
    "population" : "['general medicine and surgery patients with T2D', 'general medicine and surgery patients with type 2 diabetes (T2D', 'n=266) and surgery (n=319) patients admitted with a blood glucose (BG) between 140 and 400 mg/dl, treated with']",
    "population_mesh" : "[{'cui': 'C0086343', 'cui_str': 'General medicine'}, {'cui': 'C0038895', 'cui_str': 'operative procedures'}]",
    "journal" : "Endocrine practice : official journal of the American College of Endocrinology and the American Association of Clinical Endocrinologists",
    "dois" : "['10.4158/EP-2019-0481']"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("624edebb78036379835d29a8"),
    "pmid" : 32339033,
    "ti" : "SAFETY AND EFFICACY OF DDP4-INHIBITORS FOR MANAGEMENT OF HOSPITALIZED GENERAL MEDICINE AND SURGERY PATIENTS WITH TYPE 2 DIABETES.",
    "year" : "2021",
    "population" : "['general medicine and surgery patients with T2D', 'general medicine and surgery patients with type 2 diabetes (T2D', 'n=266) and surgery (n=319) patients admitted with a blood glucose (BG) between 140 and 400 mg/dl, treated with']",
    "population_mesh" : "[{'cui': 'C0086343', 'cui_str': 'General medicine'}, {'cui': 'C0038895', 'cui_str': 'operative procedures'}]",
    "journal" : "Endocrine practice : official journal of the American College of Endocrinology and the American Association of Clinical Endocrinologists",
    "dois" : "['10.4158/EP-2019-0481']"
}
```

i.e)
`db.collectionName.find(year:"2020")`
and other similar query dont give any output so Is there any problem in JSON data or my mongo shell command ?

Comment: Have you tried `db.collectionName.find({year:"2020"})`? Note the braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I changed two fields of JSON form string data to array of field by removing "" I was able to run the query

reformed JSON is here which give the output.
I dont know how its happen. But I got the result

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "624edebb78036379835d29a7"
  },
  "pmid": 32339032,
  "ti": "SAFETY AND EFFICACY OF DDP4-INHIBITORS FOR MANAGEMENT OF HOSPITALIZED GENERAL MEDICINE AND SURGERY PATIENTS WITH TYPE 2 DIABETES.",
  "year": "2020",
  "population": [
    "general medicine and surgery patients with T2D",
    "general medicine and surgery patients with type 2 diabetes (T2D",
    "n=266) and surgery (n=319) patients admitted with a blood glucose (BG) between 140 and 400 mg/dl, treated with"
  ],
  "population_mesh": [
    {
      "cui": "C0086343",
      "cui_str": "General medicine"
    },
    {
      "cui": "C0038895",
      "cui_str": "operative procedures"
    }
  ],
  "journal": "Endocrine practice : official journal of the American College of Endocrinology and the American Association of Clinical Endocrinologists",
  "dois": "['10.4158/EP-2019-0481']"
}
```